# Using POI, JAVA & MySQL to Compile an Excel Document

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to gather information from a MySQL database and then exporting that information to a Excel document using POI and JAVA.

The only problem I am experiencing is increasing the number after `data.put`, each time `if(rs.next())` is executed, for example:

```
Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});

            if(rs.next()) {
                data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d, "Test"});
            }
```

The `2` should increase to `3` then to `4` then to `5`, depending on the rows in the MySQL database.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int cnt=2;

while(rs.next()) 
{
    data.put(""+cnt, new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d, "Test"});
    cnt++;//increment to 3, 4, etc
}
```

try like this

Comment: For some reason, this is only writing one line.

Comment: use `while` not `if`. `if` is going to check the condition only on time.